# Is a pdo wrapper really overkill?

Tags: php, pdo

I have done some research about using a databasewrapper for my data.
However, I read some posts where people claim you shouldn't use PDO for a databasewrapper because it already is one.

That may be so, but I am still convinced that it has a lot of benefits.

1. You handle all your data actions (crud) in one class, not spread across your website files. So it's much easier to debug and handle errors.
2. You can easilly change your class with another databaseclass.
3. You don't have to repeat your code, just call the code in the databaseclass
4. Optionally you can extend the class with for example logging, statistic tests, ...

Example:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    public $connection; 
    private $host = "";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "";

    public function __construct(){      
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->username,$this->password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function insert($query, array $data){        
        $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute($data);     
        return $this->connection->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function update($query, array $data) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query,$data);
        return $stmt->rowCount();       
    }

    public function delete($query, array $data) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query,$data);
        return $stmt->rowCount();       
    }

    public function findOne($query, array $data = null){        
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query,$data);          
        return $stmt->fetchObject();
    }

    public function findMany($query, array $data = null){
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query,$data);
        return($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
    }

    public function executeQuery($query,$data = null){
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
?>
```

Instead of constantly repeating all the steps for retrieving data, you can call get() and pass a query and some optional parameters.
This is a lot more efficiënt than everytime open a connection, perform 3 lines of code and close it.

```
$db->get("select * from user where id = ?",array(1));
```

Comment: "All the steps..." - are there really that many? PDO lets you write `foreach ($pdo->query(...) as $row)`, which is about as minimal as it gets for an unprepared statement. Interacting with the database is expensive and should only happen in very specific methods to begin with instead of "all over the place", I don't get why it always has to happen in a single line.

Comment: What do you mean with very specific methods instead of all over the place?

Comment: MVC, separation of concerns. You should have a few concentrated places in your model layer where the data is retrieved from the database. E.g. `UserService::getAllActiveUsers()` or `PostService::updatePost($id, array $data)`. The only job of these methods is to interact with the database in one specific way. Inside you should spend as many lines on a proper database query as necessary, there's no advantage to make it into a single line. Having such a "simple wrapper" just seduces you to query your database from all over the place ad hoc instead of creating these central methods once.

Comment: Do you mean calling a service class method like getAllUsers in a model method? Why not perform database interaction directly in model methods like most tutorials?

Comment: Because most tutorials either get MVC wrong or don't explain it properly. The point is you only have a finite number of things you actually do with the database. Each of these things has its own method somewhere in your model. `User::getAll` to retrieve all users, `Report::monthlySales` for the monthly sales report, etc. The only thing these methods do is fire the right query to the database and return the result. Why do you need yet another database wrapper inside those methods?

Answer (score 7):

It is said because most attempts to create a PDO wrapper are indeed helpless and make things worse than with raw PDO.
Also premises, one is writing their wrapper based upon, are mostly wrong.

Let's take yours:

> You handle all your data in one class, not spread across your website files.

Quite vague statement, with no particular meaning. Surely you handle your data all across the application but using not raw PDO but using your own class.

> You can easilly change your class with another databaseclass.

But a delusion. You can't actually stick to your two helper methods - sometimes you need to use raw PDO instance.

> You don't have to repeat your code, just call the code in the databaseclass

this one is quite true. But not that useful as with any other API.

> Optionally you can extend the class with for example logging, statistic tests

This is a proper one - no objections.

> This is a lot more efficiënt than everytime open a connection, perform 3 lines of code and close it.

this is a false one. *Nobody* asks you everytime open a connection, perform 3 lines of code and close it. Even with raw PDO connection is opened only once.

However, your implementation is quite good. It doesn't add too much to raw PSO (actually, it shorten repetitions by just one line only) but still being sensible. So - I'd call this approach rather successful.

Some suggestions:

1. there is indeed no point in storing database credentials as class properties. They needed in constructor only and nowhere else
2. Why not to create a connection right in the constructor, without the need for extra method?
3. public function getOne() would be indispensable addition to your set.
4. You need to make $connection public - at least until you make all the methods available from both PDO and PDOstatement

Comment: With my first statement I meant handling all database operations.  It was indeed quite vague. I often see that people build their webpage by constantly using crud operations across the page. Instead, I am convinced that the best practice is to let one single class handle all your database operations.

Comment: Well PDO already pretends to be such a class. So, speaking of PDO, your argument is not that relevant. The main problem with wrappers, that people who writing, have even less knowledge than PDO creators, and make things worse. If only execute() returned $this instead of boolean - it would make your class indeed obsolete.

Comment: Indeed, I understand, I am definately not better than PDO creators :), I'm also not seeking to improve it, but use it in a handy way by creating methods that return objects.

Comment: It is not about your implementation (as I said, you managed to make something useful) but rather about most of implementations tried - as an explanation why it is said that wrapper is overkill. Your own also lacks many features. You can take a look at my wrapper to get an idea or two: https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql

Comment: Yes I understood. I also showed just a fragment. I updated it with the full class updated with your feedback. I just use the credentials as class properties because I have production and test credentials and I switch between them by commenting them out.

Answer (score 2):

'Overkill' is subjective.  Thats for you to decide for your particular case.  Performance-wise I doubt you'd notice any difference.

There are some possible benefits of doing something like this.  For example, you can embed query profiling and application logging into the class.  And, as you point out, you have the option of structuring the queries in a way thats easiest for you to work with and maintain.

On the other hand, the code will be less portable if it relies on your wrapper class.  You cant then take that code and use it with code that relies on PDO.  You might get around some of those limitations by extending the PDO class, rather than creating a wrapper for it.