# My PDO query seems to randomly stop working?

Tags: php

How can I troubleshoot further?  I have 3 styles of querying.  This is for a fetchType = 'single' ( single row that is) and a populated parameterArray

```
public function query($fetchType, $queryType, $parameterArray=null)
{
    $query=$this->sql_array[$queryType];
    if($parameterArray==null)
    {
        $pdoStatement = $this->db_one->query($query);
        $results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    $this->db_one->quote($query);
    $pdoStatement = $this->db_one->prepare($query);
    $results = $pdoStatement->execute($parameterArray);
    if($fetchType=='single')
    {
        $results = $pdoStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else if($fetchType=='multiple')
    {
        $results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

My results is coming back false and I see no data in the sql table.

I verified that the queryType exists in the lookup table and that other queries are working.

Here is the actual query.  I inserted new lines to make readable.

```
"signup_insert" =>            
"INSERT INTO credentials 
(h_token, h_file, h_pass, email, name, picture, privacy) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Here is the debug code I created:

```
$pipe['debug_h_token']=$h_token;
$pipe['debug_h_file']=$h_file;
$pipe['debug_h_pass']=$h_pass;
$pipe['debug_email']=$this->TO->get('email');
$pipe['debug_name']=$this->TO->get('name');
$pipe['debug_picture']=$picture;
$pipe['debug_privacy']=$privacy;

$test = $this->DBO->query('single', 'signup_insert', array(
    $h_token,
    $h_file,
    $h_pass,
    $this->TO->get('email'),
    $this->TO->get('name'),
    $picture,
    $privacy
));
$pipe['debug_test'] = $test;
```

Comment: You have 7 parameters, so you need 7 values. What is being passed into `$parameterArray`?

Comment: I inserted the debug code above ... is it odd to be inserting data in one query and also fetching data ... perhaps?

Comment: Honestly, it seems like you're going out of your way to make it more complex and harder to work with. Why not just run regular queries, its 2-3 lines  each time? I recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20664742/4535200

Comment: What do you mean ... I want to be simple about things ... how can I modify ?

Comment: What I mean is that, in the end, it's probably simpler to use regular methods, and not create wrappers/classes of your own. This function you're writing is also for selecting, not inserting. Which makes the point again, stay to original methods, it's probably easier and safer.

Comment: You can only fetch results from a `SELECT` query. What are you expecting `$pdoStatement->fetch()` to return from an `INSERT` query?

Comment: oddly this use to work ... it was during my learning phase.

Comment: I need this up ... any ideas on what to change ... either way it appears I'm running my code correctly -> quote, prepare, execute, query

Comment: There was a column in the sql table that did not have a default value being set ... this was the cause ... have no idea what triggered it.